# Can't delete Google contact (fix Google Contact duplication)

Tags: google-contacts

For some unkown reason I have many duplicate contacts in my Google account. More than 18.000 duplicates. This causes big problem on Android devices.

I have tried several suggestions which I found in forums. Such as https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/WIUTlfWCe98 .

I made "Find duplicates" and then "Merged", but it didn't help.

I also tried using special android apps for duplicate contact deletion, but it didn't help either, as contact was reapearing from my google account.

Finally I realized I have one particular contact repeating for thousands times. I tried deleting it in https://contacts.google.com/preview/all, but it didn't help. Strangely contact is reapearing after deletion.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found the solution which works for me!

1. Go to your Google contact page
   https://contacts.google.com/preview/all.
2. Press "More" and then "Export".

   [image: "More" menu]
3. Press "Go to Old Contacts".

   [image]
4. You will find old interface Google Contacts and there you will be able to review your "Other Contacts".

   [image: "Other Contacts"]
5. I found all duplicates are inside "Other Contacts". Now we need to delete 18.000 duplicates.
6. In order to quickly delete I pressed "Settings" and then selected 250 items to display per page.

   [image: Settings]
7. I used "Select All" and then "More" & "Delete". In around 15 minutes I managed to delete all duplicates (in batches of 250).

   [image: "Other contacts" with no entries]
8. Finally I deleted all Android Contact using this solution: [Droidiser: How to delete all contacts at once from any Android device](http://www.droidiser.com/2013/04/delete-all-contacts-android.html) and then synced Contact to the latest Google Contact status. Finally after so long time my contacts are fixed!